# How to configure 17.10 desktop's systemd-resolve dns via terminal?

Tags: systemd-resolved

I can do this via network setting's manual dns input field yet if I like to manage it via terminal (ssh), what may I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Open the file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` in a text editor and make the desired changes. Afterwards run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` to activate the changes.

Common options to change in that file are in the `[Resolve]` section, for example:

```
DNS=192.168.1.1
Domains=mynet
```

Will set your dns server and search domain.

The [resolved.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man5/resolved.conf.5.html) manual page is a good source for information on how to edit the configuration file.