# I can't get my dns server to work (1.1.1.1)

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

I changed my dns settings as shown by the website https://1.1.1.1/

The changes did not work
I just want to get on 1.1.1.1 lol

Comment: "changes did not work" Well, how did you test that ? Also, what's your Ubuntu version ? Ubuntu 18.04 uses a bit different configuration than say 16.04

Comment: lol there's a blocked site that becomes unblocked when I enable 1.1.1.1 on my windows pc.. https://ibb.co/NCy0vxK I'm on 18.04

Comment: I tried deleting the space after the comma, no difference

Comment: OK, try either `systemd-resolve --set-dns=1.1.1.1` in terminal or editing config file as shown in  https://askubuntu.com/a/1024720/295286  Also try `systemd-resolve --set-dns=1.1.1.1 && systemctl restart systemd-resolved`  (that is set DNS and then restart the service which we're configuring) If that doesn't work you'd have to wait for someone to post an answer using `netplan` which is the network manager in 18.04, however I don't have experience with `netplan` so cannot suggest how to best edit its config files

Comment: Didn't work, just to be clear, this is the response I'm supposed to get in the terminal, right?:
https://ibb.co/Tvt244p

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to have worked after a restart - although, is there a way to add the backup server of 1.0.0.1 and the ipv6 servers, (606:4700:4700::1111 - primary, and 2606:4700:4700::1001 - backup)

Answer (score 2):

As resolved ( no pun intended ) in the comments, setting DNS on 18.04 can be done by configuring `systemd-resolved`  either via

```
# note, is the device via which you access internet - wireless or ethernet 
# interface name can be found via `ip addr` command
systemd-resolve --set-dns=1.1.1.1 --interface=wlp2s0
```

or  via editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to contain the following lines

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1
```

As reported by OP in the comments, they had to restart the system in order to make changes apply, which also suggests a `sudo systemctl restart networking` would be sufficient without restart.

---

For multiple DNS servers, [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved) suggests either providing multiple nameserver addresses as in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf` file:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

OR via separate file for fallback nameserver  in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/fallback_dns.conf`

```
[Resolve]
FallbackDNS=1.0.0.1
```

IPv6 addresses can be used just the same